# Get OWIN Startup class type at runtime

Tags: c#, owin

In an other project, We have multiple MVC applications that share the same core library. In the core library we detected the running application by extracting this information from the namespace of the GlobalAsax type that was started:

```
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxType().BaseType.FullName
```

Now we want to do the same in an OWIN-only environment. In essence, I'm searching for an equivalent of the above, something like `GetOwinStartupType()`.

Does anyone know if something like this exists?

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` returns `System.Web` and I also don't want to inspect a StackTrace at runtime.

Comment: I assume you don't set the Owin startup class in the AppSettings, otherwise you could fetch it from there. Did you try to search for the OwinStartup attribute?

Comment: Also searching the attribute doesn't work. Imagine a unit-test project that references two applications where one test can start a test server with Startup of app1 while the other test starts a test server for app2

Comment: Ok, that's a pickle. Injecting it would be out of the question? Or setting a value by the OwinContext?